# curl --data-binary in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, curl, invoke-webrequest

If I have a `curl` command such as:

```
curl <url> \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'API-Key: <key>' \
  --data-binary '{"blah":"blah {\n  blah2(accountId: id, integrations: {int1: {Vms: [{Id: id2, resourceGroups: [\"test1\", \"test2\", \"test3\"]}]}}) {\n    integrations {\n      id\n      name\n      service {\n        id\n        slug\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n", "variables":""}'
```

What would be the equivalent to `--data-binary` within Powershell? Some answer stated just running `curl.exe`, others mentioned to change the content-type. This does work as a shell script fine though. Just wondering if its possible to convert it to use `Invoke-WebRequest` within Powershell.

Comment: Use either `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebRequest` with the `-InFile` parameter.

Comment: I'm not reading from a file though- just inline json being sent with `--data-binary`

Comment: Will sending a JSON body work?  You can use the `-Body` parameter.

Comment: The `-Body` parameter seems to not care about being binary or not- works as expected, though it does require specific escape characters- thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

-Body parameter works with the payload

Comment: Please flesh this out in more detail to help future readers, including explaining what specific escape characters you had to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use either Invoke-RestMethod or Invoke-WebRequest
with -Body parameter but remember to convertto-json as the content-type is 'application/json'

example:

```
$body = @{"blah"="blah";"blah2"="blah2";}
$jsonBody = ConvertTo-Json $body
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post  -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $Headers -Body $jsonBody
```